# What does this statement do @@RowCount > 0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Taken from the book  : "Julia Lerman - Programming Entity Framework "

when creating a new entity in EF :

```
   var contact = Contact.CreateContact(0, "Camey", "Combs", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
   context.Contacts.AddObject(contact);
   context.SaveChanges();
```

The generated sql :

```
   exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Contact]([FirstName], [LastName], [Title],
   [AddDate], [ModifiedDate])
   values (@0, @1, null, @2, @3)
   select [ContactID]
   from [dbo].[Contact]
   where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ContactID] = scope_identity()',
   N'@0 nvarchar(50),@1 nvarchar(50),@2 datetime2(7),@3 datetime2(7)',
   @0=N'Camey',@1=N'Combs',@2='2009-08-30 09:27:31.7449098',
   @3='2009-11-30 09:27:31.7449098'
```

What is @@RowCount > 0 used for in the where clause ?

I'm not sure of what it does according to msdn it returns the number of affected rows , 
so as i understand it , this is just a way the verify that the   Contact record was added 
they could of also have written @@ROWCOUNT = 1

is this correct ?

Comment: The query back against the base table seems unnecessary. You could do the same with `SELECT scope_identity() AS ContactID  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0` except if getting the exact datatype of `ContactID` returned is important. Maybe a check that triggers haven't altered anything I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@@Rowcount` is a special variable. It will always hold the number of records changed or returned by the last statement. In this case, the last statement was the insert. By using `@@Rowcount > 0` in the where clause, you make sure the select only matches any records if the insert statement succeeded.

If they had used `@@Rowcount > 1` instead, that statement would never be true. That insert statement will only insert 1 row. 1 is not > 1.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake before i ment to write that they could of wrote @@RowCount = 1 , see Edit above

Comment: @eranotzap in this case, `= 1` would like work. In the general case, it's better to use `> 0`, because you can write insert statements that will create more than one row.

Comment: yes i got that , i just wanted to verify for this specific case that the check was for one row affected due to insert.

Answer (score 3):

@@Rowcount = the number of rows affected by the last statement

In your case, this checks that the insert did not encounter an error such as a row with the same primary key

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing in that query that requires you to use dynamic SQL. Also I find doing that sort of @@rowcount check in the "where" clause to be a little silly. Since you've just inserted, either it'll break with error before it reaches that select statement or that @@rowcount condition will always be true.

I would replace it with this...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contact](
    [FirstName], [LastName], [Title],[AddDate], [ModifiedDate])
VALUES (N'Camey', N'Combs', null, '2009-08-30 09:27:31.7449098', '2009-11-30 09:27:31.7449098')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Also the datetime values you're trying to insert probably should be replaced with `GETDATE()` instead.

Here is documentation on [@@rowcount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)
And here is [scope_identity()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: Maybe there is some configuration's in certain db's that do not  break on exceptions , so that might be a good reason to perform that check. (But this is just an educated guess)